# Ionic 5 http request ssl sertificate errror

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I am using ionic 5 and create http request with httpclient.My url=http://examples.com but ı am looking console my url looking different=https://examples.com.
does ionic convert http urls to https in itself?